# good way to horizontally align enumerate items

Tags: enumerate

I have a collection of multiple choice questions that use the enumerate environment. In some cases, I'd like the align the answers (items) in specific ways. For example, I might want to align numbers at their decimal points like this:

[image] [image]

I aligned the decimal points in this example using phantoms and llaps, but I'm curious if there's a better/slicker way that doesn't require as much manual tweaking -- something analogous to an align* environment that I could wrap around the enumerate items and just stick ampersands where needed?

Since I have a lot of multiple choice questions I'd like to change, I'm hoping to make this as easy as possible, and it would be great if it didn't break my enumerate environments.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the meaning of life?
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item $1.618$    
      \item $2.71828$
      \item $3.14159$
      \item $42.00$
      \item $1000.00$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the meaning of life?
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item $\phantom{1000.000}\llap{1.618}$
      \item $\phantom{1000.00000}\llap{2.71828}$
      \item $\phantom{1000.00000}\llap{3.14159}$
      \item $\phantom{1000.00}\llap{42.00}$
      \item $\phantom{1000.00}\llap{1000.00}$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can emulate the labels of an enumerate environment in the first column of a table, with package `listliketab` and use `siunitx`to align the numbers in the second column on the decimal dots, with the `S` column type. You even can cross-reference the items:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx, listliketab}

    \begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}\renewcommand\thetabenum{(\alph{tabenum})}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum}
\begin{tabular}{@{}L S[table-format=4.5, table-number-alignment=center]@{}}
  \tabitem & 1.618 \\
   \tabitem\label{row-2} & 2.71828 \\
   \tabitem & 3.14159 \\
   \tabitem & 42.00 \\
   \tabitem & 1000.00
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

We read in row \ref{row-2} an approximate value of Euler’s number $e$. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that's helpful and formats this case how i want. i'm ideally hoping to change my existing database less drastically though. and also, there are a lot of other cases when i want to align differently. e.g. i have answers with equations and pos/neg integers that i'd like to align at the first digit. would be great if there's a general way of doing it.

Comment: Solutions might be very specific, depending on the case at hand. I suggest you edit your question with samples of the cases you meet in practice.